# Using Bootstrap 3 form theme in symfony2 does nothing

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, symfony

I'm trying to use Bootstrap3 form theme in my Symfony2 forms as described here:
http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-bootstrap-form-theme

I'm adding this in main config:

```
twig:
    form:
        resources: ['bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig']
```

And adding this in every form:

```
{% form_theme form 'bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig' %}
```

classes are applied to html elements but no theme is applied.
I checked page source and found no bootstrap.css (Should I include it by myself? )
I included bootsrap but still I had a very bad and messy full width textboxes and nothing else got affected!
My symfony is `2.6.4` (upgraded from `2.5.10`)
What is the problem?

Comment: if you're using a theme (or making your own) you have to include css in the base file.

Comment: As @SamiaRuponti said, you need to import the `css` and `js` files on your own. However, you don't need to set `form_theme` on your forms if you have already defined the resource in your `config.yml`.

Comment: @tftd - one of you needs to turn one of those comments into an answer ... with a little elaboration of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Symfony >= 2.6 a bootstrap form theme is already available as part of the framework and you don't need to do anything more than set the resource in your `config.yml`:

```
twig:
    form:
        resources: ['bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig']
```

You don't need to define `{% form_theme %}` in your templates because the form template/theme is already available. What you need to do is to include the bootstrap css/js files in your `app/Resources/views/base.html.twig` (or whatever your base template is).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Then you just extend this base template in your other view templates and everything should be working fine. For example:

```
// App\MyBundle\Resources\views\homepage.html.twig
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}
    // your html/forms/etc goes here; this content will then be rendered with the base.html.twig file as part of the "content" block in base.html.twig.
{% endblock %}
```

For more information you should read the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html).